# Polymer elements not rendered on Safari 7.0

Tags: javascript, html, safari, polymer

I guess this is not a very original question for those already familiar with Polymer. Anyway I have started using it from two months, developed a lot of code, enjoyed it and now I am realizing it doesn't work on Safari (or at least the code I have developed doesn't work). I am importing the polymer platform.js as described in the doc but I think there has to be something I am still missing.

No errors are reported in the safari console

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari 7.0 Requires the use of the polyfill, which handles issues on browsers that have not integrated web components yet:

```
<!-- Polyfill Web Components support for older browsers -->
<script src="components/platform/platform.js"></script>
```

Be Aware that platform.js has a gotcha associated with it right now(hopefully soon to be fixed). The platform.js call must be placed *above* your import links in the html document.

Note: Code from the [Polymer Project recommendation](https://www.polymer-project.org/)

Comment: which is exactly what I am doing. Still the custom elements are not rendered

Comment: Can you post your imports with the platform.js call?

Comment: I think I am going to create a stand alone example to share via GitHub but I can do that this evening. Thank you for your kind help

Comment: The problem was I was running the platform.js in the custom component itself thus loading it twice. Thank you